# Is it possible to show some kind of image when opening gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there any possible way to show splash screen of random pictures(`.jpeg` or `.png`) when opening `gnome-terminal` everytime?

Comment: Which terminal? Gnome terminal? Some other terminal that runs in X? The virtual terminal (that you see after pressing `ctl-alt-f1`)?

Comment: gnome terminal `ctl-alt-t`

Comment: @djeikyb Question revised based on OP's comment.

Comment: Also, are you meaning a splash screen, or do you want a custom picture as the background of the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about what you exactly want to do...but one solution is to add the commands inside *.bashrc* 
This shell script(bashrc) is executed everytime you open your terminal(*ctrl + alt + T*)

open the terminal and enter the command

*emacs .bashrc*

Emacs will open the bashrc file and then you can add the new command at the end of bashrc file(bashrc is stored in your home dirctory and it is hidden by default)

for example

*eog /path/for/imagefile*

this will open image everytime you open your terminal..
**Before making any changes to bashrc just make sure that you take the backup so that even if you change or edit any other things you will be able to roll back your changes**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First use cowsay utility

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

Add this at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

```
cowsay -f "$(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | sort -R | head -1)" "Welcome"
```

Every time you open terminal you get a funny image with welcome message.

If you want some quotes then install fortune

```
sudo apt-get install fortune
```

And add this following line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

```
cowsay -f "$(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | sort -R | head -1)" "$(fortune -s)"
```

If you want this a learning basis then add the  following at the end of ~/.bashrc file

```
cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | shuf -n 1 | cut -d. -f1) $(whatis $(ls /bin) 2>/dev/null | shuf -n 1)
```

Comment: sorry not cowsay(not artwork).

Comment: So what kind of random pictures you want to draw ?

Comment: like *.jpeg pictures